# Upright greek letters

Tags: discussion, feature-request, math-display

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could produce upright greek letters on stats.SE? In my documents, I usually do this using the $\LaTeX$ [upgreek package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/upgreek).

#### Edit

I am uploading an image of what I hope the upright greek letters look like. The $\LaTeX$ code to produce this document is included below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, upgreek, booktabs, tabularx, colortbl}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{preview}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
 & Deterministic & Non-deterministic \\
\midrule
Scalar & $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ & $X, Y, Z$ \\
Vector & $\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\gamma}$ & $\boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{Y} \boldsymbol{Z}$ \\
Matrix & \cellcolor{blue!25}$\boldsymbol{\upalpha}, \boldsymbol{\upbeta}, \boldsymbol{\upgamma}$ & $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{Z}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{preview}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might check the MathJax website and forum. Out of purely idle curiosity: Is the motivation behind your question some aesthetic preference or is there a (statistical) communication issue at play here that you're seeking to resolve?

Comment: @cardinal Thanks. I will look up the MathJax website.

The motivation is statistical communication. I follow slightly atypical notation (but found in some multivariate statistics textbooks) to denote parameter matrices by upright bold, parameter vectors by regular (italic) bold. 
I distinguish deterministic and non-deterministic quantities using cases -- uppercase (greek or roman) for non-deterministic and lower case for deterministic.

Comment: @cardinal, some scientific standards organizations (e.g. NIST, IUPAC) stipulate italic font for letters representing variables or functions, & roman font for letters representing mathematical constants, descriptive terms, or SI prefixes.  So an upright pi for the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter, but an italic pi for the parameter of a binomial distribution.

Comment: @Scortchi: (+1) This is a very interesting observation. It seems to be of a different motivation than fg nu's, though. At any rate, these are manifestly *not* conventions in (the vast majority of) mathematical writing (nor, that I am aware, in its brethren in statistics, engineering, etc.)

Comment: @scortchi Thanks for the comments. As cardinal has noted, there are, regrettably, few common notational conventions in statistics, although in econometrics, [there has been some attempt at unification](http://www.bus.lsu.edu/hill/writing/abadir_magnus.pdf). The best thing to do appears to be to develop a reasonable personal system of notation, and stick to it.

Comment: @cardinal, this convention seems to be rarely observed for mathematical constants represented by Greek letters, occasionally observed for mathematical constants represented by Latin letters (e.g. e for the base of natural logarithms), & often observed for operators (e.g. d for the differential operator).  Geography as well as discipline may play a part - & I'd bet what's easiest in $\LaTeX$ too.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to use `unicode` within the $\LaTeX$ code:

> `$ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B1}} $`
>
> `$ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B2}} $`
>
> `$ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B3}} $`

will result in

> $ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B1}} $
>
> $ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B2}} $
>
> $ {\bf \unicode[Times]{x3B3}} $

See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Greek_in_Unicode) for the Greek Alphabet for the unicode for each letter.

Note that you can use regular $\LaTeX$ commands for upright uppercase Greek letters with `\rm`. For example, using:

> `$ {\rm A, B, \Gamma} $`

results in

> $ {\rm A, B, \Gamma} $

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I I hope the end result looks like. I must admit, I am not a huge fan of mixing unicode with LaTeX.

Comment: No, me neither! But I think with MathJax it's the only way to get the non-italic lower case Greek letters. I'd love to be proven wrong though!